# How can I load test the system for 100 thousand unique users by running Jmeter test on several AWS instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter, load-testing, master-slave

I want to load test the system for 100 thousand unique users by running Jmeter test on several AWS instances (Master, Slave).
These users are registered in the site that I want to load test and I have them in csv file.
I have to use different set of users from each instance as the test case during load run involves different i.e. unique set of users.

Comment: Not clear on what you're asking. Are you asking for a tutorial on how to use jmeter?

Comment: I want to load test with unique registered users and I have list of all the users (20 sheets -> 5k unique users each) in csv files (csv file contains the mobile number and password for each registered user).
Now as I will be running the load test on multiple aws instances say 20 (master and slave), is it possible to keep different csv of 5000 users on each aws instance with same name?
As I will be giving the path in jmx file (on master aws instance).

Answer (score 0):

JMeter can be executed in [distributed mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) so you need to have:

- 1 machine to act as a **Master** - which will load the [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan), orchestrate the test and collect the reusults
- X number of slaves where X depends on:

  1. Nature of your test (number of requests, size of requests/responses, number of pre/post processors/assertions/etc.), see [What’s the Max Number of Users You Can Test on JMeter?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what%E2%80%99s-the-max-number-of-users-you-can-test-on-jmeter/) article for guidelines on properly sizing your JMeter test
  2. Hardware specifications of your AWS instances as there are different [AWS EC2 instance types](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) with different number of CPUs, amount of memory, etc. 
     Remember that you need to divide your "lakh" to the number of the slave machines, for example if you have 10 machines you should define 10k users in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group), if you have 20 machines - 5k users, etc.

You might also find projects like [jmeter-aws](https://github.com/jneyer/jmeter-aws) or [jmeter-ec2](https://github.com/oliverlloyd/jmeter-ec2) useful